# How create new field inside the struct using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, struct, field

I have 1 struct (the name of the struct is "patient_1") 
[image: struct patient_1]

consist of 1 cell (the name the cell is "A1")
[image: cell A1]

inside the cell A1, there are 36x1 values which all of them are the struct.
[image: patient_1.A1]

inside the patient_1.A1, there 2 fields, such as the screenshot below
[image: patient_1.A1{1, 1}]

My question is how to create new field inside the struct patient_1.A1{1, 1}?

This is my code at the moment:

```
% looping each struct and put each name of files as variable using
for i=1:l_files1
    label1(i,1) = string(files1(i).name); % get name field 
    patient_1.A1{i,1}.name = label1(i,1);
end
```

`label1` on the code is just string of label that I want to assign on the field.

So the result, each struct should have a new field like this:
[image: new field on the struct]

I realized that new field already succeeded create on the  struct, but on the MATLAB I got this error:

```
Unable to perform assignment because dot indexing is not supported for    variables of this type.

Error in Main (line 38)
    patient_1.A1{i,1}.name = label1(i,1);
```

this is the screenshot of error:
[image: error]

According to the problem, is there anyone can help me to solve this?

Comment: You should try to avoid creating cell arrays with structs inside them. Create a struct array instead. It is a lot easier to manage. This problem would be trivial in that case. Your problem is that `patient_1.A1{6,1}` is not a struct, but a cell array. If you had a struct array, this would not be possible.

Comment: I don't see the purpose of `A1` in this case, but maybe you have a use for it. But you can create a struct array as follows: `patient_1.A1(10).data = []; patient_1.A1(10).textdata = {}; patient_1.A1(10).name = "";`. -- So the idea is that you index `A1(i)` instead of `A1{i}`. This forces all fieldnames among the elements of `A1` to be identical. `A1(1)` will have the same field names as `A1(10)`.

Comment: Yes, I think the problem is on the A1{6,1} is a cell. It is quite weird because among all the object it should be struct like the others object inside the A1. But I will try to change it to the struct as you said. If that success, I will let you know. Thank you for the idea! @CrisLuengo

Comment: Thank you, I have tried your advice, and it works well now. I have upvoted your comment above. @CrisLuengo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, we need avoid create the array of cells with structs inside them.
Create a struct array instead. This problem is that `patient_1.A1{6,1}` is not a struct, but a cell array.

So, just create `patient_1.A1` as a struct and get the value inside the structs straight away.